# How to make material design chips in android studio?

Tags: android

This is a page I have on web:

[image]

As you can see, it's based on Google's Material Design (not complete yet) and it uses [chips](https://material.angular.io/components/component/chips) to show a list of items, floated besides each other and located at the center of the parent container.

However in Android, this is what I've come to:

[image]

I used a linear layout and inside it, I put some items. The count of these items is not pre-determined. The length of each item's text is not determined and might be one small word or three words and they should be clickable.

I can't find the notion of `chips` in Google's support library, and I can't float them besides each other.

Can you help?

Comment: Getting them to go besides each other is easy, just change the orientation of the linear layout.  Your problem will be when they go off the edge.  Really I think your best course here is not to use individual views-  use a single custom view that figures out where to draw the text and does its own hit testing.  Although you could also go for a custom layout and calculating the position of each child when you layout, I just think the ondraw tends to be easier.

Comment: @GabeSechan, *Your problem will be when they go off the edge*, that's exactly the problem. We don't have the notion of **floating** things in Android I guess. Is there a component already made for that? I'm really surprised to find less the more we search. Because this is a very usual requirement. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by floating?  Do you mean the raised 3d look?  That's called elevation, newer versions of android support it out of the box, older ones via the support library.  If you mean something like the floating action button that stays at a fixed place on screen no matter how much you scroll, I don't see how that applies here.  If you mean something else then you're using float in a way i've never heard it used.

Comment: is this shown as web view? with that you should change the web page

Comment: @GabeSechan, sorry for the terminology confusion. I used web terminology. By floating, I mean CSS floating. That is, you tell a list of items to start sticking to their parent container from left for example, and then next item sticks to the left of previous item, until they hit the right border of the parent container, then they automatically go and populate the next line.

Comment: That's definitely not an Android design feature (which is probably why I didn't know it, I don't do web pages).  I don't know of anything built in that does that.  You could always write your own FloatingLayout class extending ViewGroup, and customize onMeasure/onLayout to tell the child views where to go.